# resume activity after phone suspended

Tags: android, sleep, suspend

I want to create an app for android ,some thing like screen saver

I want to start app(or resume paused activity) instantly after display turning off,and phone locked,and display turn on and my app start showing, 
This is not custom lock screen ,because i want to lock screen do not change, if press back button key among app is showing ,exit from app and show the default lock screen.
How to do i?

**Update:** I need this for API >8(android 2.2)

Thanks

Comment: Have you heard about Day dream... I guess that is what will help you in making the application

Comment: No,i'm not hear about Day dream,can you let me more details?thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example on [DayDream](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-42-how-create-daydream) .This is a new implementation came with Jelly Bean. This would help your requirement

Comment: @odr_m9611 :I guess this is what you where looking for

Comment: Thanks,I thought "turning off the screen" == "sleep mode"

Comment: Do not have a solution for my problem?

Comment: There is nothing as of low end Api to get the sleep notion of the device.That is why you wouldn't find a system app like a clock or so .I guess if you target jelly bean and above then its feasible